eclipse CDT cython error:pycore_atomic.h:38:32: error: ‘memory_order_relaxed’ undeclared here
my configuration like this:
ubuntu  24.04
gcc     13.3.0
eclipse CDT 11.6.1

When running this:
/data/py_envs/bin/python /data/Software/IDE/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_12.2.0.202409031913/pysrc/setup_pydevd_cython.py build_ext --inplace

I got a bunch of errors:
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:38:32: error: ‘memory_order_relaxed’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   38 |     _Py_memory_order_relaxed = memory_order_relaxed,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:39:32: error: ‘memory_order_acquire’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   39 |     _Py_memory_order_acquire = memory_order_acquire,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:40:32: error: ‘memory_order_release’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   40 |     _Py_memory_order_release = memory_order_release,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:41:32: error: ‘memory_order_acq_rel’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   41 |     _Py_memory_order_acq_rel = memory_order_acq_rel,
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:42:32: error: ‘memory_order_seq_cst’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   42 |     _Py_memory_order_seq_cst = memory_order_seq_cst
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:46:5: error: unknown type name ‘atomic_uintptr_t’
   46 |     atomic_uintptr_t _value;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/python3.12/internal/pycore_atomic.h:50:5: error: unknown type name ‘atomic_int’
   50 |     atomic_int _value;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

I have tried all solutions which can be gotten from googling,any suggestions or solutions are appreciated.

I suspect you just need to set your C compiler to C11 mode. But I don't know exactly how you'd do that for this package

@DavidW Thanks,I will try to figure out how to set c11 mode
